Snowflake - calculated column referring to itself
I have this data set:



DAY
STATUS
OPEN_BAL
CLOSE_BAL




1
C
159
158


2
F
158
0


3
F
205
205


4
F
205
204


5
F
204
203



I need to update the OPEN_BAL and CLOSE_BAL columns based on specific rules when the status is F.
The rules are as follows:

The OPEN_BAL for the current day should be the CLOSE_BAL from the previous day
The CLOSE_BAL for the current day should be OPEN_BAL + 1
The subsequent OPEN_BAL and CLOSE_BAL should rely on the previously calculated values

For example:

For Day 2, the OPEN_BAL is 158 (correct), and the CLOSE_BAL should be 159
For Day 3, the OPEN_BAL should be 159, and the CLOSE_BAL should be 160
For Day 4, the OPEN_BAL should be 160, and the CLOSE_BAL should be 161, and so on

Here is the sample data and the expected output:



DAY
STATUS
UPDATED_OPEN_BAL
UPDATED_CLOSE_BAL




1
C
159
158


2
F
158
159


3
F
159
160


4
F
160
161


5
F
161
162



I'm trying to achieve this with the query below, but I'm encountering issues because the LAG function only works correctly when the values in the stock table are accurate. I realize that my current solution is incorrect, but I haven't found a way to make the LAG function reference itself. Does anyone know if it's possible to do this within a SELECT query?
WITH RankedRecords AS (
    SELECT 
        YEAR(TRY_TO_DATE(TRIM(f.open_date ), 'yymmdd')) folio_yr,
        s.folio_mo, s.folio_no,
        f.tt_status status,
        IFNULL(try_cast(s.open_bal AS FLOAT), 0) as open_bal,
        IFNULL(try_cast(s.close_book AS FLOAT), 0) as close_bal,
        LAG(close_bal) OVER (ORDER BY folio_yr, fol_mo, fol_no) AS prev_close_bal
    from ops_fivetran_prd_raw.azure_sql_midstreamt_us_tms6data.Stock s
    join ops_fivetran_prd_raw.azure_sql_midstreamt_us_tms6data.FolioStatus f
        on s.folio_mo = f.fol_mo
        and s.folio_no = f.fol_no
        and s.term_id = f.term_id
        and upper(trim(s.term_code)) = upper(trim(f.term_code))
        where s.supplier_no = '0000000000' and s.term_id = '00000BN' and folio_yr = '2024' and s.folio_mo = '08' and s.prod_id = 'MOBRED'
),
UpdatedBalances AS (
    SELECT 
        folio_yr, folio_mo, folio_no,
        status,
        CASE 
            WHEN status = 'F' THEN prev_close_bal
            ELSE open_bal
        END AS expected_open_bal,
        CASE 
            WHEN status = 'F' THEN prev_close_bal + 1
            WHEN status = 'F' THEN open_bal + 1
            ELSE close_bal
        END AS expected_close_bal
    FROM RankedRecords
),
FinalBalances AS (
    SELECT 
        folio_yr, folio_mo, folio_no,
        status,
        expected_open_bal,
        expected_close_bal,
        LAG(expected_close_bal) OVER (ORDER BY folio_yr, folio_mo, folio_no) AS prev_expected_close_bal
    FROM UpdatedBalances
)
SELECT 
    folio_yr, folio_mo, folio_no,
    status,
    CASE 
        WHEN status = 'F' THEN COALESCE(prev_expected_close_bal, expected_open_bal)
        ELSE expected_open_bal
    END AS open_bal,
    expected_close_bal AS close_bal
FROM FinalBalances;

FOLIO_YR, FOLIO_MO, FOLIO_NO are represented by DAY column on the examples.

Hi - even accepting that your sample data/expected result is a simplified version of your actual data, your SQL doesn't seem to align with your data. For example, you say that the rules depend on the status (with C/F values) but your SQL seems to be using WHEN folio_no = 1 for this piece of the logic. It would be helpful if you either simplified your SQL to match your sample data or made your sample data match your SQL (i.e. include definitions and data for the Stock and FolioStatus tables)

I’ve updated to the correct query, but I’m still not getting the expected result. My challenge involves use a recursive LAG (?) function that refers to itself

is there a gap in dates? for example if right after day1 is day 5 , is it still prev_close_bal + 1 or it will be prev_close_bal + 5?
